# Insert multiple records into a table with an existing ID column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a cross-reference table that looks like this:

```
  id
  ppid
  tid
  createUser
  createDate...
```

I want to get rid of this table because the data is corrupted. I have already deleted all of the corrupted data and added a record to the table I want to put this information into.

The table looks like this:

```
id   tid   field1   field2....
```

The id of table2 is the same as the ppid in the cross-reference table. What I am trying to do is to put the tid from the cross-ref table into table2 where the associated id is equal to the ppid from the cross-ref table. There are about 1500 records so it isn't too large but large enough I don't want to write the values 1500 times.

I am using SQL Server 2017

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an update with a join

```
update t2
    set t2.tid = t1.tid
from table2 t2
inner join crossRefTable t1 on t1.ppid = t2.id
```